# How to load custom javascript code in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to load js file in my not-found component.

I'm reed information from https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular So, create file, added it in angular.json. In example they show how to do it with onClick event. But I need to load this js file when not-found component is load and I don't know how to do it.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare const notFound: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';

    notFound(); // can't use directly - Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration.ts(2391)
}
```

What I need to add in not-found.component.ts and not-found.component.html to load this script when user load not-found page?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the  OnInit interface
like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
declare const notFound: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'test';
  ngOnInit() {
      notFound();
  }
```

}

Comment: I try it but - https://pastebin.com/T46G5024 & I never call this function in html...